# How am I using the formula wrong? (calculating PI with nested square roots)

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to calculate the approx of pi with Viete's formula of nested square roots of 2

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int k; //variable for user input
    int n = 1; //built integer that causes the program to loop
    double result;
    //greeting message, start of program
    cout << "Welcome to the Approx PI program.\n";
    cout << "Please enter in a value for k...\n";
    cin >> k;
    //if user inputs a number outside the interval
    while (k < 1 || k > 30)
    {
        cout << "Invalid ---k must be >=1 and <=30\n";
        cout << "Please enter in a value for k...\n";
        cin >> k;
    }
    //calculating PI with the nested square root formula
    while (n <= k - 1)
    {
        result = sqrt(2 + result);
        n++;
    }
    result = pow(2, k) * sqrt(2 - result);
    //outputs the result, end of program
    cout << "Approx PI =         " <<setprecision(20)<<fixed<<result<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But when I enter 28, it gives me 4:

```
Welcome to the Approx PI program.
Please enter in a value for k...
28
Approx PI =         4

Process finished with exit code 0
```

When I enter 29 or 30, the result is 0:

```
Welcome to the Approx PI program.
Please enter in a value for k...
30
Approx PI =         0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I think k=30 should be giving me:

```
Approx PI = 3.14245127249413367895
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you point to the line of code that first assigns a value to `result`?

Comment: Wasn't this asked earlier today and the bug with result mentioned in the comments? I remember seeing the same code and bug.

Comment: Yes @drescherjm -- it's almost like [everyone's copying the same bug from each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73848325/).

Comment: Side note: When dealing in integers, `pow(2, k)` is a much more expensive version of `1<<k`, so long as `k` is not so large that it will overflow an `int`. If `int` is its usual 32 bits and `k` <= 30, you're good to go.

Comment: I guess the variable name changed but it was essentially the same.

Comment: @NathanPierson       line 25

Comment: @Aacro There aren't line numbers in Stack Overflow questions. What's the content of that line?

Comment: @NathanPierson result = sqrt(2 + result);

Comment: @Aacro Do you see any issue with the fact that `result` is on the right hand side of that assignment?

Comment: You should set the warning level in your compiler to the maximum. And fix all warnings before going further

Comment: On the first iteration `result = sqrt(2 + result);`  is  `result = sqrt(2 + garbageValue;` where using the `garbageValue` is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare `result`, you should assign it some value. Otherwise, you cause [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) because at line 25 you use the uninitialised memory `result`.